# EEG data preprocessing with mne python

Tags: r.net, mne-python

I have Physiological EEG emotion dataset named *"Deap"*. I want to analyze and visualize the data through MNE but it has its own format.

How can I load my personal data for pre-processing, data format is (.dat)?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle

with open('s01.dat', 'rb') as f:
    y = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

This one works for me.
Of course, the ".dat" file is in the same directory as this code.

Comment: Python version 3.8

Comment: For Python 2.x use import cPickle